# Laravel show PDF file to certain users

Tags: laravel, pdf

> What I have done

- Users can send to each other PDF.
- I store that PDF in folder

> What I am trying to do

I am trying to make the PDF visible for the receiver user.

example: **Alice send pdf to Bob** I want only **Bob** can see this PDF.

> What is happening:

Everything works fine except that the PDF link is not protected which mean that anyone can view this PDF because they got the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use policy to do this, you can define a role call pdfOwner, when you store the pdf, make Bob and Alice as the pdf owner.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#writing-policies